# Does Ἵνα (hina) clause convey certainty or uncertainty?

Tags: greek

I have realized that the hina clause means certainty that a particular thing will happen, I don't know if this is unique to koine greek or appears in other forms of Greek. is it accurate to say that a hina clause means there is little doubt something will happen. Such as in John 14:16 what does the may convey there. I have read many places that the hina clause does not imply uncertainty when paired with the subjunctive but implies that in order for the end to happen, the first condition must be fulfilled. But to me I cannot help but read the "may's" as "this may happen or it may not happen".

> And I will ask the Father, and He will give you another Helper, that
> He **may** be with you to the age--

In the above example I wonder if the reading is that The Holy Spirit is with believers forever or that He *might* be with believers forever. Or in other words is Jesus saying The Holy Spirit *could* be with believers forever but not necessarily or *will* be with believers forever.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Something being contingent or conditional doesn't mean its fulfilment is unsure uncertain, but it is only contingent upon the given clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about English on the confusion of [**maybe** vs **may be**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=maybe%20may%20be).

To quote from [an answer, from English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13560/when-and-how-to-use-the-words-maybe-and-may-be):

> Grammatically, “maybe” is an adverb, while “be” is a verb, here used with “may” as an auxiliary verb. The word “perhaps” is another adverb with a meaning very similar to “maybe,” while “might” can be used as an auxiliary verb with much the same meaning as “may.” But “mightbe” is not a word, and “be” is almost never used without an auxiliary verb so “perhaps be” still needs one.
>
> The suggestion of swapping “may be” with “is” (or another form of the verb “to be”)[to check whether you need *maybe* or *may be* in your sentence] is also quite good: it changes the meaning, but has the same grammatical role, so if “is” works grammatically, then “may be” will also work grammatically. (from KRyan)

*May, should, would, could, ought, can* are [modal verbs](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/modal-verbs-and-modality?q=Modal%20verbs). There are other expressions that contain modal meaning as well. They are used with the main verb ***be*** or ***abide***. Together they are a *verb phrase*: "May be", whereas *may be* are separate words. John 14:16 KJV: he may abide with you; ESV: to be with you; SLT: should remain with you. It is not related with probability, only *maybe* the *adverb* means *perhaps*, shows uncertainty.

Subjunctive means possible, contingent, or hypothetical; not a fact. The context will determine whether the sense is of possibility, or contingency.  *Therefore do not be anxious, saying, ‘What shall we eat?’ or ‘What shall we drink?’ or ‘What shall we wear?’* (Matt 6:31) shows possibility, uncertainty of future.

General Definition of Subjunctive, by Daniel Wallace:

> The subjunctive is the most common of the oblique moods in the NT. In general, the subjunctive can be said to *represent the verbal action (or state) as uncertain but probable*. It is *not* correct to call this the mood of *uncertainty* because the optative also presents the verb as uncertain. Rather, it is better to call it the mood of probability so as to distinguish it from the optative. Still, this is an overly simplistic definition in light of its usage in the NT.

> The single most common category of the subjunctive in the NT is after *hina* ἴνα, comprising about one third of all subjunctive instances. There are seven basic uses included in this construction: purpose, result, purpose-result, substantival, epexegetical, complementary, and command. Its usage in the Koine period has increased from the classical as this construction came to be used as a periphrasis for the simple infinitive.

Optative, from Latin *opto* means *I wish*. It simply shows wish, prayer, blessing or curse.  Just as the indicative is the mood of “reality” and the subjunctive the mood of “potential,” the optative is the mood of “wish.” This fits better with certainty, we *hope* that he dies, we *hope* he is surely blessed, etc.

The certainty of the condition is based upon believer's fulfilling the condition to be saved. *They shall never perish ἀπόλωνται* John 10:28. In the promise of the Holy Spirit, that it will/should/would abide with you forever. You should only see it in the sense of **potential & contingent**, and not certain/uncertain, for [*certainty*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/certain) pertains to the degree of psychological surety or doubt. The promise of God is assured, but only its fulfilment is contingent and conditional on man's part. Or, I should say, the certainty of the subjunctive is dependent upon the conditions or terms given in the clause, not *independently* uncertain.

### [Maybe or May be?](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/maybe-or-may-be)

> May be
>
> In the phrase may be /meɪ bi:/ may is a modal verb and be is a main or
> auxiliary verb. Here may and be are two separate words, whereas maybe
> is one word:
>
> -There may be a train at 10.00am.
>
> -Not: There maybe a train at 10.00am.
>
> -He may be waiting for us.
>
> Typical error
>
> We use may as a modal verb in the phrase may be. They are two
> separate words. We use maybe as an adverb:
>
> - This may be the last match that he plays for Barcelona.
> - Not: This maybe the last match that he plays for Barcelona. Maybe as an adverb
>
> Maybe /ˈmeɪbi/ is an adverb and it means the same as perhaps. It is
> written as one word:
>
> - Maybe no one will come to the party.
> - Not: May be no one will come to the party.

Answer (score 0):

The conjunction ἵνα (hina) is a conjuction which means (BDAG)

1. **marker to denote purpose, aim, or goal, *in order that, that***, final sense, (a) with subjunctive not only after a primary tense, but also (in accordance with Hellenistic usage) after a secondary tense

- after a present tense, Mark 4:21, 7:9, Luke 6:34, 8:16, John 3:15, 5:34, etc
- after a perfect, Matt 1:22, 21:4, John 5:23, 36, etc
- after a present or aorist imperative, Matt 7:1, 14:15, 17:27, 23:26, etc
- after a future, Luke 16:4, 18:5, John 5:20, 14:3, 13, 16, 1 Cor 15:28, Phil 1:26
- after a secondary tense; imperfect, Mark 3:2, 6:41, 8:6, Luke 6:7, etc

In the case (as quoted above) we have the the subjunctive mood (may be with") following a future tense ("he will give").

Thus, John 14:16 is simply saying that the Father would give (future - after Jesus leaves) the Helper/Advocate/comforter **in order that** He may be with you forever.  That is, the purpose of the giving the Holy Spirit is so that we may enjoy the personal company of the Father via His Agent, the "Advocate/Comforter.

The reason for the subjunctive mood, "*may be with you*" is subtle - while the Father is eager to give the gift of the Holy Spirit, we are not forced to accept the gift.  Thus, the presence of the Father via the Holy Spirit is dependent upon the recipient's acceptance of the gift.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comment it was helpful. I still am wondering about the Hina clause though, perhaps I did not understand fully, does it imply certainty that once a condition is fulfilled the last condition will happen? Is this unique to Koine greek?

Comment: @kittymae - conjunctions of purpose are very common in many languages.  The element of uncertainty in John 14:16 is because the outcome is dependent on the recipient's acceptance of the Gift - some accept and some reject.